# Python Syntax: How do I check if 'x' exists in the return value?

Tags: python, return, contains

I have a python syntax question.

If result() passes in 3 arguments and therefore returns something in the form of (x, y, z), how do I check if 'x' exists in the return value?

I want to check if either thing, thing2, or thing3 from the function result() are 'X'. Right now, I am writing "While 'X' in result:" ...I don't think I am doing this right though, because result is not a string.

I just want to see if result, which might be (a,b,c) or (1, 2, 3) or (x, y, z) contains 'x'. For instance, if the result was (x,y,z) and I asked if result contained 'x', it would return true. If I asked the same question and result was (a, b, c), it would return false. How would i go about doing that?

```
def result(thing, thing2, thing3):
  # Returns a new thing (deepcopied) with thing3 space taken by thing2
  new_thing = thing.copy()
  new_thing[thing3] = thing2
  return new_thing

def terminal(thing, k): 
  while 'X' in result:
```

Comment: The question is a little too abstract. Determining whether a value is `in` an object depends on what that object is and how it decides if it contains something. It would be easier to provide a real answer if you had a concrete example with the actual objects you are using. For example, if `thing` is a list  you can just use `in`: `'b' in ['a', 'b', 'c']` <- `true`, but if thing is something else, who knows?

Comment: `'x' in result` is probably what you are asking for, `in` works with all objects that are iterable (note: it doesn't check for nested objects)

Comment: Hi Tom, thank you. But despite the return value of termianl, is it valid to say while 'x' in result in the first place? Or should I do something like "if result[1] == X:..." ?

Comment: @Mark You're right, I should have provided more context...thing is represented as a 2d numpy array, thing3 returns all possible indexes of blank spaces in that array, and thing2 is set to new_thing[thing3] as it says in the code.

Comment: @Tom Karzes, does what I just said to Mark change anything about the last point you made? I should have been more specific.

Comment: It would be best to provide example input values and expected output values. Can you give an example call to `result` that works as you expect?

Comment: @sofiarosabianchi It sounds like you just want to search the return value to see if it contains some specific value, in which case using `in` should work, provided equality comparison is the correct test for the value's presence.  But you need to call the function, i.e. `'x' in result(...)`.

Comment: Actually, looking at this problem more closely now, I see that it's actually more specifically the thing2 of result that I need to check. I actually need to see if thing2 contains 'x'. So in this case, should i say "if 'x' in result[1]:..." ?

Comment: Another quick question...if thing3 returns all possible indices of blank spaces in the thing array, does that mean that thing3 returns a list or a string?

Answer (score 0):

I think the statement `while 'X' in result:` doesn't work the way you expect because `result` is the function not the output of the function, which would be `result()`. However `terminal` can't call result in an obvious way unless you want something like `result(thing, k, k)` because `result` has three required arguments but `terminal` only has two inputs.

Edit:
If you know `result` returns an iterable (like a list or tuple), then it's always valid to do `while 'X' in result(arg1, arg2, arg3):` without some kind of manual indexing in the form `result(arg1, arg2, arg3)[i]`